# How can I interpolate a random octet into a CIDR block in Terraform?

Tags: random, terraform, interpolation, ipv4

I have the following *random_test.tf* Terraform file, which I've successfully initialized:

```terraform
resource "random_integer" "octet" {
  min     = 0
  max     = 255
}

variable "base_cidr_block" {
  description = "Class A CIDR block in RFC 1918 range"
  default = "10.0.0.0/8"
}

provider "null" {
  base_cidr_block = "10.${random_integer.octet.result}.0.0/16"
}

output "ip_block" {
  value = var.base_cidr_block
}
```

I'm using the [null provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-null) as a placeholder to test defining a 10.0.0.0/16 CIDR block with a random second octet. However, *base_cidr_block* is always `10.0.0.0/8` even though I'm expecting it to be assigned something like `10.100.0.0/16`, which would then be shown on standard output as *ip_block*. Instead, I always get the default:

```
$ terraform plan

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_integer.octet will be created
  + resource "random_integer" "octet" {
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + max    = 255
      + min    = 0
      + result = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + ip_block = "10.0.0.0/8"
```

Running `terraform apply` then always sends `ip_block = "10.0.0.0/8"` to the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with, although I may not understand the intent.

First, I've created a module. I'm using the random_integer, and setting a keeper:

```
variable "netname" {
  default = "default"
}

variable "subnet" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/8"
}

resource "random_integer" "octet" {
  min     = 0
  max     = 255
  keepers = {
   netname = var.netname
  }
}


output "rand" {
  value = random_integer.octet.result
}

output "random-subnet" {
  value = "${cidrsubnet("${var.subnet}", 8, random_integer.octet.result)}"
}
```

Next I call the module, passing in my keeper, and optionally the subnet:

```
module "get-subnet-1" {
  source = "./module/"
  netname = "subnet-1"
}

output "get-subnet-1" {
  value = module.get-subnet-1.random-subnet
}

module "get-subnet-2" {
  source = "./module/"
  netname = "subnet-2"
}

output "get-subnet-2" {
  value = module.get-subnet-2.random-subnet
}
```

Finally, my output:

```
    Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
    
    Outputs:
    
    get-subnet-1 = 10.2.0.0/16
    get-subnet-2 = 10.6.0.0/16
```